# Publish Post using Facebook API giving error

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook SDK Open Graph APIv2.0  to publish custom story. I followed steps given in following "[URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph)" to create custom story. But when I am trying to publish object using  API calls it is giving following response:

```
Encountered an error posting to Open Graph: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x8a6ca10 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=500, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 1;
            message = "An unknown error has occurred.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 500;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x8d573c0, state: FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended, loginHandler: 0x8d570d0, appID: 173370299532104, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x8d576f0>, expirationDate: 2014-07-25 07:03:07 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-05-26 08:25:30 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    installed,
    "public_profile",
    "publish_actions"
)>}
```

**Note:** I am not providing app id for deep linking since I do not have any app to link with.
Please can anyone know what I am doing wrong. I searched on Google but I did not find any solution to this problem. I am using developer account.

Answer (score 0):

the app id for deep linking is not the apple app id
it is the Facebook app id

you need to follow the instructions at 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

in the "Step 3: Obtain a Facebook App ID section"

Comment: That part I have already done. I am talking about "Enable deep linking" which says "One of the most attractive features of sharing Open Graph stories from your app, is that when people engage with these stories they can be directed to your app or your app's App Store page, driving engagement and new installs. This is done through the use of app links, in a process called deep linking.
 Enable it from the app dashboard on the ''iOS'' section of your app's settings and provide your app's iPhone and/or iPad App Store IDs. "

Comment: when you create an App on itunesconnect you get an App ID you can use that id